# Allow executing python file one at a time

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a python file(it is a native messaging host) which is executed not from the cmd but from a chrome extension which executes it without a console window. Each time the chrome extension is reloaded the python file is executed again without exiting the last one. So my question is is there a way in python to track if this file is running at the time and close that process so there is only the most up to date  one left?

Comment: in your python script, you can add some code so that will find the running process and kills it before starting new one

Comment: If there are multiple python processes running how can i get the exact process?

Comment: `tasklist` in batch will give you all the running task then use `findstr` to match your program